# Warning: force:lightning:lwc:start is not a sfdx command

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, lwc-dev-server

I am trying to use the new [LWC Local Development Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html).

I've run command:

```
sfdx update
```

So I know I am using the latest version of the CLI.

And I've installed the plugin:

```
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
```

And it seems to install fine:

> Successfully validated digital signature for
>   @salesforce/lwc-dev-server. Finished digital signature check.
>   Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server...

And then I authorised a Sandbox org.

But when I run the command to start the server:

```
sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start
```

I this this:

> »   Warning: force:lightning:lwc:start is not a sfdx command.
>   Did you mean force:lightning:lint? [y/n]:

When I run this command:

```
sfdx plugins
```

I get a result of:

> no plugins installed

**Questions**

1. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it / get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a Scratch org not a standard Sandbox.

```
System Requirements

Developer Hub-enabled org
Most recent stable version of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or Edge web browser
Windows—Windows 7 (64-bit and 32-bit) or later
Mac—macOS 10.11 or later
Linux—Ubuntu 14.0.4 or later
Salesforce CLI
```

Reference

- [Local Development (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/lwc/localdev)

Comment: I forgot to mention I had authorised a sandbox org. I've updated the question

Comment: I tried by Creating the project, authorize it to a Sandbox, then installed the server and then ran the command to start the server. I had no issues. Can you try to authorize first before installing the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are on node and doing local development try to install dependencies using 'npm install' and try again .

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved my issue in Windows 10:

1. Update your python version via Admin cmd
   C:\WINDOWS\system32>"**choco upgrade python -y**"

(System restart)

2. Install sfdx dev server plugin:
   "**sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server**"

then try this from vs-code:
**sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start**